# Regex pegar mais que uma ocorrência numa string

Tags: c#, regex

Tenho a minha regex `(\d{2})`.

E tenho minha string `12 hoje vai 45 na serra pelada 55 ou 75`.

Como faço para minha regex pegar todas as ocorrências da string? Ela está pegando apenas a última.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(\d{2})*` para zero ou mais ocorrências. `(\d{2})+` para uma ou mais ocorrências.

[Veja um teste aqui](http://regexr.com/3ajrl).

Para iterar sobre todas as ocorrências, use:

```
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches("12 hoje vai 45 na serra pelada 55 ou 75", "(\d{2})*")) 
{
    // m.Value mostra o valor encontrado, m.Index o índice na lista de 
    // expressões encontradas.
}
```

[A referência está aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: O que interessa é iterar os `Matches`.  Acrescentar + ou * não é necessário.